# compare two consequetive rows of teradata table

Tags: sql, teradata

If i have a table like

[image]

In my table i want to compare every two consequetive row. Suppose if the employee_status is 'yes' and after it is 'pro'. Then I want to add another column and write 'problem' in both rows and 'no problem' in other rows.
Like,

- 1 yes problem
- 2 pro problem
- 3 pro no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`/`lag()` -- or the Teradata equivalent -- and a `case` expression:

```
select t.*
       (case when employee_status = 'yes' and
                  max(employee_status) over (order by employee_no rows between 1 following and 1 following) = 'pro'
             then 'problem'
             when employee_status = 'pro' and
                  max(employee_status) over (order by employee_no rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) = 'yes'
             then 'problem'
             else 'no problem'
        end) as problem_col
from t;
```

Comment: lead and lag cannot be used in teradata. As i mentioned its a teradata table. So I am afraid i cannot use this way. Thanks.

Comment: @umair . . . I have no idea why Teradata doesn't support those functions.  There is an easy work-around.

Comment: they did not implement these functions in Teradata yet. There is a way around using Min and max or next/-value. But I dont know how to use them. Though i tried something like  `SELECT a.*,
case when
   MIN(a.employee_status) --previous row
   OVER (ORDER BY a.employee_no
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 'yes'
and
   MIN(a.employee_status) -- next row
   OVER (ORDER BY a.employee_no
         ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) = 'Pro' 
   then 'Problem'
   else 'No_Problem'
   end as Status
FROM labs_megafab_platform.employee a`

Comment: LAG/LEAD are implemented in TD16.10+

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Yay!  It is about time.